# WMI event filter query in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

I'm trying to add two different WMI events to an SCCM server with a PowerShell script that someone else wrote.  I have to make the two event queries into one query and I'm not sure how best to do it.  I've tried it a bunch of different ways so far.  Here's the code:

```
Function WMI-InstanceFilter
{
# Function Started
LogTraceMessage "*** Function WMI-InstanceFilter Started ***"
Write-Verbose "*** Function WMI-InstanceFilter Started ***"

$PropertyHash = @{
    QueryLanguage = "WQL";
    Query = "";
    Name = "Name";
    EventNameSpace="root/sms/site_$($SiteCode)"
    }

$Script:InstanceFilter = New-CimInstance -Namespace root/subscription -ClassName __EventFilter -Property $PropertyHash -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here's the two event queries I need to somehow combine and put into the query line:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent Within 900 Where TargetInstance ISA 'SMS_Package' and TargetInstance.Name like 'drivers - %'"

SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent Within 300 Where TargetInstance ISA 'SMS_Package' and TargetInstance.Name like 'BIOS - %'"
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can combine the name queries like this:  `TargetInstance.Name LIKE 'drivers - %' OR TargetInstance.Name LIKE 'BIOS - %'`.  However, I don't think you can combine the timings, so you will need to choose a single duration for the WITHIN clause as it is now a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with WQL in your queries and you can only have a single WITHIN value - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/within-clause so you'll either have to pick 300 (seconds = 5 minutes) or 900 (seconds = 15 minutes) or a compromise value somewhere between them.

Your combined SELECT statement would look like this

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 900 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'SMS_Package' AND TargetInstance.Name LIKE 'drivers - %' OR TargetInstance.Name LIKE 'BIOS - %'
```

Change the WITHIN value to what you think best for your needs.

Do you need both drive & bios at the same time or could you use a parameter driven switch statement to swap between them?

Something like this

```
Function WMI-InstanceFilter {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [ValidateSet('Bios', 'Drivers' )]
  [string]$InstanceType
)

# Function Started
LogTraceMessage "*** Function WMI-InstanceFilter Started ***"
Write-Verbose "*** Function WMI-InstanceFilter Started ***"

switch ($InstanceType) {
 'Bios' {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent Within 900 Where TargetInstance ISA 'SMS_Package' and TargetInstance.Name like 'drivers - %'"
        }
  'Drivers' {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent Within 300 Where TargetInstance ISA 'SMS_Package' and TargetInstance.Name like 'BIOS - %'"
        }
}

$PropertyHash = @{
    QueryLanguage = "WQL"
    Query = $query
    Name = "Name"
    EventNameSpace="root/sms/site_$($SiteCode)"
    }

$Script:InstanceFilter = New-CimInstance -Namespace root/subscription -ClassName __EventFilter -Property $PropertyHash -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Comment: No, Don't have to do them at the same time, just wasn't sure of any way else to do it. What would a parameter driven switch statement look like?  Let me know and I'll accept your answer either way.

Comment: I've added a possible function to the answer

Comment: Trying running what you wrote but it didn't work and the log file said "Variable ErrorMessage set to System.ArgumentException: Could not infer CimType from the provided .NET object."

Comment: Do the queries run outside of the function ie can you manually create the CIMinstance?

Comment: Nope.  "New-CimInstance : Could not infer CimType from the provided .NET object."